# Generating audio from integer list data

Tags: sound

I have integer list data which I am outputting to MIDI format, however the list data range of values is much greater than the MIDI note range, so is it possible to use the min and max value in the list and scale that to a desired audible frequency range and output a continuously changing frequency following the values in the list, to have no defined notes?  Thanks.

cheers,
Jamie

Comment: You might look at the function Rescale.

Comment: Thanks, once I've rescaled so all values are in a range 0 to 1, there will be more than 88 notes, ie there could be 10000+ different values, which I'd like to be distinct frequencies at least to a resolution of ~+-1Hz frequency rather than being binned into 88 notes.   The notes should be played at 10 notes per second with fixed tempo, I tried this: vscaled = Rescale[v];
ListPlay[vscaled, SampleRate -> 10]
but that didn't seem to output the notes.

Comment: The list data I have ie these 48 notes: v={27, -18, 1, 4, 23, 26, 13, 32, 19, 22, 41, 44, 31, 18, 37, 24, 27, 46, 33, 36, 23, -6, -3, 16, 19, 38, 41, 12, -1, 2, -11, 8, 11, -2, 17, 4, -9, -6, 13, 16, 3, 22, 9, 12, 31, 34, 53, 8}

Comment: MIDI is based on notes with pitches in the range of 0 - 127. If you want to use more pitches than that, then you can use the MIDI "pitch bend" command, but you will have to program this yourself.